# JSONP working with GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, google-maps, wfs, geojson

I'm in this scenario (fighting with the same origin police issue):

I have a map initialized with OpenLayers and a WFS request trough the Protocol.Script object that is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){this.metadata={};b=OpenLayers.Util.extend({},b);null!=this.alwaysInRange&&(b.alwaysInRange=this.alwaysInRange);this.addOptions(b);this.name=a;if(null==this.id&&(this.id=OpenLayers.Util.createUniqueID(this.CLASS_NAME+"_"),this.div=OpenLayers.Util.createDiv(this.id),this.div.style.width="100%",this.div.style.height="100%",this.div.dir="ltr",this.events=new OpenLayers.Events(this,
this.div),this.eventListeners instanceof Object))this.events.on(this.eventListeners)} has no method 'addOptions'
```

The error seems to be related with OpenLayers lib (maybe the version, actually is the 2.13), but i don't know.

What i tried is:

```
consulados = OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Consulados", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
            url: "http://"+ip+':'+port+"/geoserver/wfs",
            callback: 'handleResponse',
            params: {
                service: "WFS",
                version: "1.1.0",
                srsName: "EPSG:4326",
                request: "GetFeature",
                typeName: "topp:tazmania_roads",
                outputFormat: "text/javascript"
            },
        })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to lay aside openlayers and make a try with simply a jQuery.ajax request.
Take care with the url. Here you can found details to build the request url  [Geoserver output formats](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html)

```
var url = "http://"+ip+":"+port+"/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName= topp:tazmania_roads&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson";

jQuery.ajax({
                    jsonp: false,
                    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(jsonObject) {
                        alert(jsonObject);
                        //handler(jsonObject);
                        create_GeoJSON(jsonObject);
                    }
});
```

When the client side receives the data (if there isn't any errors) success "body" is called to manage the JSON object and work with this.